# wp_enqueue_script error with `ID`, `post_title`, `post_name` of none object

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to make my first plugin, but when I try `wp_enqueue_script` the script file, I get errors about the `ID`, `post_title`, `post_name`, even though its a single page (i.e. not posts kind of page).

```php
// enqueue scripts
function myplugin_enqueue_scripts( $hook ) {
    if ( !is_page('my-page'))  { return; }

    // define script url
    $script_url = plugins_url( 'public/myplugin.js', __FILE__ );

    // enqueue script
    // Below line cause the error
    wp_enqueue_script('myplugin', $script_url);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_enqueue_scripts', 1);
```

I get this error message:

```
[23-Jun-2020 21:59:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /usr/www/users/sexerxm/example.server.com/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3994
[23-Jun-2020 21:59:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /usr/www/users/sexerxm/example.server.com/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3996
[23-Jun-2020 21:59:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_name' of non-object in /usr/www/users/sexerxm/example.server.com/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3998
```

Within `myplugin.js` is one line:

```js
console.log("Please work");
```

I also tried the `template_redirect` hook but no difference. Why is this error being generated?

Comment: Are you trying this on a clean installation? Does the error persist if you try a regular string as the URL instead of the `plugins_url` function result?

Comment: Additionally its not a clean installation, the person has a woo commerce plugin installed and a few others. I am not sure i am allowed to disable them. I tried a high and low add_action priority to try negate other plugin interference but jad the same result

Answer (score 0):

### Issue 1

I was not seeing the embedded object in javascript because:

The error was, I thought `plugins_url` always resolved to the plugins dir, it resolves to the dir of `__FILE__`:

In my situation `myplugin.js` and `myplugin.php` are both in the same `public/` dir, so this:

```
$script_url = plugins_url( 'public/myplugin.js', __FILE__ )
```

Was resolving as (notice the double `public`):

```
http://server.example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/public/public/myplugin.js
```

instead of

```
http://server.example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/public/myplugin.js
```

### Issue 2

I still see the error, however even with my plugin disabled, and managed to track it down to WooComerce by looking at the debug network tab and seeing the ajax request.